# Mouse flickering and moving randomly

Tags: display

I observe random movement of cursor on screen when restarting updates Ubuntu packages.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was due to two optical devices being connected to CPU. Removing the other solved it.

Following commands might help:

1. `sudo apt-get update`
2. `sudo apt-get upgrade`
3. `cat /proc/modules | grep usb`
4. `lsusb` (This lists the devices connected to USB port.)

Comment: Yes, it's a very trivial thing...